# What if the catch statement code causes an error?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, elmah

I am using Elmah for error reporting in my applications.

Usually if there's an error I catch it, craft a custom message and throw it back again.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var e = new Exception("Failed to get Intake Statuses <br />" 
+ " (@PageNumber = " + pageNumber + ", @PageSize = " + pageSize + ".<br />" 
+ " Error: " + ex);

    ErrorLogger.LogErrorManually(e);

    throw new Exception(e.Message);
}
```

Now the issue arises if there is an error in the custom error that I am created.

What are the best practices to handle that? Do I create another sub Try/Catch?

Comment: Is `LogErrorManually` prone to throwing? Perhaps it should try/catch itself. Otherwise, it doesn't look like you need to worry about it. If you did, another try/catch sounds like your best bet.

Comment: Does the method calling this have a `try...catch` of its own?

Comment: Throwing a new Exception will cause you to lose the stack trace.  Consider instead just `throw;`, or throwing a new exception that includes the original exception as the inner exception.

Comment: What do you mean an error in the custom error?

Comment: `Do I created another nested Try/Catch loop?` Try/catch is not a loop. It's a statement. See [try/catch C3 Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx).

Comment: Instead doing `throw new Exception(e.Message);` it would be much better to either do `throw new YourOwnCustomException("Your Message", ex);` to create your own custom exception with a message and having the original exception set as the inner exception or just do `throw;` to re-throw the original exception with all of it's information in place. You really should never throw the base `Exception` class, it is considered a bad practice.

Comment: @Eric J., Scott.. Thanks I will refactor my statements to do that. I wasn't aware of the ramification>

Comment: @mason. Yes you are correct. I miswrote. 

Bradley. The problem happened when the variable pageNumber was undefined, the main statement threw an error.. then the catch statement failed too.

Comment: Then you should check for null if you want to avoid nested try/catch.

Comment: I could, but that would be a lot of work as every single method has a different custom error and it would mean writing 100 checks for null. 
I don't mind using nested try catch, i just wanted to know if it is the best way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Create a method say A with try catch and lets call your function whose catch you have given in description as B.
2. In your B catch just use throw so that your stack trace will not go away.
3. On exception in B catch it will navigate to catch A and thus you can show the message as you like it.

Comment: It would be a lot better if this was explained via a code example.

Comment: It took me a little reading to understand, but this makes sense. 
A code example though would be perfect for anyone else who stumbles upon this question. I will mark it as an answer afterwards.